# Configuration.GetConnectionString returns null when running asp.net core on VS Code but fine on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, connection-string, visual-studio-code, npgsql

Here is my **appsettings.json** file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=db;User ID=postgres;Password=root"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I retrieve the connection string:

```
// Only works when run through visual studio not on vs code
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```

My **launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\Chlx\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.0\\Chlx.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

My **tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\Chlx\\project.json"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: How exactly are you "running" it through VS Code?

Comment: I am running it through the debug pane ".Net Core Launch (Web)" . I can set breakpoints and the method to get the connection string returns null on vs code

Comment: How do you setup configuration in your startup?

Comment: Check `environmentVariables` in launchSettings.json.

Comment: Please check my edit guys. I added a launch.json and tasks.json

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You run the program from the root (solution level) and not from the project. Change your "cwd" in the launchsettings.json to ${workspaceRoot}\src\Chlx\

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: Or add applicationsettings.json to the root folder. That fixed it for me :)

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 2.0 I have two projects: WebApi and DataAccess. The WebApi contains the appsettings.json. In the parent directory (containing the two projects) it is the solution file. I was experincing the same issue and: Copying the appsettings.json at the level of the solution or running the app from the WebApi project, any of those resolved my issue

Answer (score 3):

The Configuration property is defined in the Startup class and it is initialized thru dependency injection. Here is the sample for a project created with dotnet new mvc -au Individual

```
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```